# Отфильтровать синхронно значения в нескольких массивах

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, графика, обработка-изображений

Есть растр с тремя RGB-каналами. Необходимо оставить в них только те значения, которые в сумме дают белый цвет или близкий к нему. Всё остальное заменить нулями, т.е. сделать чёрным цветом.

Каждый канал, я копирую в `numpy.array` и по отдельности через `numpy.where` я могу отфильтровать.

Но как сделать через NumPy такое условие?

```
for i in range(0, len(red_scanline) - 1):
    if red_scanline[i] <= 200 or green_scanline[i] <= 200 or blue_scanline[i] <= 200:
        red_scanline[i] = 0
        green_scanline[i] = 0
        blue_scanline[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще один многомерный массив использовать, но если хочется три отдельных массива одинаковой формы отфильтровать (не тестировано):

```
threshold = 200
black = ((red_scanline <= threshold)
         | (green_scanline <= threshold)
         | (blue_scanline <= threshold))
red_scanline[black] = 0
green_scanline[black] = 0
blue_scanline[black] = 0
```

Скобочки нужны. См. [Numpy array, how to select indices satisfying multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3030480/4279)

Связанный вопрос: [Fastest way to zero out low values in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623849/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library)](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) для подобных задач. Он предназначен для задач, связанных с машинным зрением и обработкой картинок.

[Пример исходной картинки](https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/clouds.jpg?w=1390&crop=1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

url = 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/clouds.jpg?w=1390&crop=1'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,img = cap.read()

lower = np.array([200,200,200])
upper = np.array([255,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
#cv2.imshow('image',res)
cv2.imwrite(r'C:\download\result.jpg', res)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]