# Помогите с OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Код должен выводить HSV изображение, но не получается. Не могу разобраться.

```
import cv2

position = cv2.imread('rf.png')

print(type(position), position.shape)

cat_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(position, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

red_low = (0,0,255) 

red_high = (86,78,121)

red_hsv = cv2.inRange(cat_hsv, red_low, red_high)

cv2.imshow('rf', red_hsv)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сток изображене. на выходе только черный фон.

Comment: Отформатируйте код

Comment: [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with`cv::inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv)

Comment: `red_low = (0,125,0)` и `red_high = (8,255,255)`.

Comment: что именно вы хотите рисовать? Белую маску на черном фоне или что-то другое? Что-то вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837914/211923) ?